# Append lists of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values are lists.

```py
n = {'d1': [1, 2, 3], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
m = {'d1': [4, 5], 'd2': ['d', 'e']}
```

I am trying to have as an output.

```py
{'d1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

I tried the following:

```py
for k in n:
    for k in m:
        n[k] += m[k]
```

The above code gives a wrong output.

```py
> print(n)
> {'d1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'e']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can't use `k` twice, the inner one overrides the outer one.
- You never check if you are adding the same keys.

Assuming `n` is the "master" dictionary, you don't even need the inner loop:

```
for k in n:
    n[k] += m[k]
```

will result with `n` being

```
{'d1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate one of the two dictionaries and extend the list:

```
for k in n:
     n[k].extend(m[k])

print(n)
```

---

```
{'d1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate key/value pairs and extend from that information

```
n = {'d1': [1, 2, 3], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
m = {'d1': [4, 5], 'd2': ['d', 'e']}
for key, vlist in n.items():
    vlist.extend(m.get(key, []))
```

This avoids a lookup in `n` which should be a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the changes and explanation in the code. You can also use the extend function instead of the inner loop but time complexity remains the same in both cases.

```
n = {'d1': [1, 2, 3], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
m = {'d1': [4, 5], 'd2': ['d', 'e']}

for i in n:             #iterates through the keys in n
    for j in m[i]:      #to iterate through the same key in m
        n[i].append(j)  
print(n)
```

output:

```
{'d1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

Comment: Don't bother with `for j in m[i]`, just use `n[i].extend(m[i])`.